# SQL group by within a group

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, aggregate-functions

How can we use group by within separate categories? That is treat each category as it's own group and then group by something else within the category.

For instance in this Image, I would like to group by quarter only within a particular ISSN.

[image: sample data]

Expected result would be

[image: expected result]

Comment: GROUP BY both ISSN and quarter. What about different years?

Comment: please tag the sql you using i.e sql server, mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to group by more than one column:

```
select issn, quarter, count(*)
from t
group by issn, quarter
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add columns -as prioritized- to group by, example:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable GROUP BY ISSN, Quarter
```